# custom svg elements (d3)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Higher Level Description:

I have an SVG file that I load via AJAX and then use d3 to manipulate the elements. The SVG file describes a graph (nodes and edges) and each node has a bunch of ancillary information associated with it that is contained in external files, e.g. a description of the node. I would like to preprocess the SVG file to contain this ancillary data rather than making a bunch of AJAX calls, but I'm not sure of the proper way to include this information.

To simplify the problem a bit:

I have an SVG file with `<g>` elements that describe a node in a graph and I would like to preprocess the SVG file so that the `<g>` elements contain a description of the node as well as a list of other nodes (this list describes the inlinks and outlinks for the node in the graph). Should I create a custom SVG namespace as described [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/extend.html) and make my own elements to hold this data, or would it be better to create a javascript hashtable that links node -> ancillary information. The end goal is to access this ancillary information when a user clicks on a node.

Comment: If you want to display the data only when the user clicks on a node, it seems better to me to keep it all in Javascript and add the information as requested.

Comment: Agreed -- d3 ("data-driven documents") is meant to generate SVG visuals from data, not data from SVG files. I would consolidate all the node data into one file, call it once on load, then reference via node id or whatever.